# How to run manually produce an elf executable using ld?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I'm trying to get my head around how the linking process works when producing an executable. To do that I'm reading [Ian Taylor's blog series](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38) about it, but a lot of it is beyond me at the moment - so I'd like to see how it works in practice.

At the moment I produce some object files and link them via gcc with:

```
gcc -m32 -o test.o -c test.c
gcc -m32 -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -m32 -o test main.o test.o
```

How do I replicate the `gcc -m32 -o test main.o test.o` stage using `ld`?

I've tried a very naive: `ld -A i386 ./test.o ./main.o`

But that returns me these errors:

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `./test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: i386 architecture of input file `./main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
./test.o: In function `print_hello':
test.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
test.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `puts'
./main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

I'm most confused by `_start` and `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` being missing - what additional info does `gcc` give to `ld` to add them?

Here are the files:

`main.c`

```
#include "test.h"


void main() 
{
    print_hello();
}
```

`test.h`

```
void print_hello();
```

`test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>


void print_hello()
{
    puts("Hello, world");
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to understand how compilation works, elf format, ... and I have done a few days ago what you are trying to do. I could tell you that it depends of library in your file and many other things. Could you add, in your post, your test.c and main.c files and I will try to give you a solution with some explanations. Almost, what I have done and why, what I have understood ?

Comment: @Stef1611 I added the contents of the files

Comment: `gcc -v -m32 -o test main.o test.o` will show you exactly what gcc is doing, including the invocation of ld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sam : I am not the best people to answer your question because I am a beginner in compilation. I know how to compile programs but I do not really understand all the details (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)
So, I decided this year to try to understand how compilation works and I tried to do, more or less, the same things as you tried a few days ago. As nobody has answered, I am going to expose what I have done but I hope an expert will supplement my answer.

Short answer : It is recommended to not use ld directly but to use gcc directly instead. Nevertheless, it is, as you write, interesting to know how the linking process works. This command works on my computer : 
`ld -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o test test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/libc.so /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/lib/crtn.o`

Very Long answer : 
How did I find the command above ?
As n.m suggested, run gcc with -v option.
`gcc -v -m32 -o test main.o test.o`

> ...
>  /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2 ... (many
>   options and parameters)
> ....

If you run ld with these options and parameters (copy and paste), it should work.
Try your command with -m elf_i386 (cf. collect2 parameters)
`ld -m elf_i386 test.o main.o`

> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; ....

Look for symbol _start in object files used in the full ld command. 
`readelf -s /usr/lib/crt1.o` (or objdump -t)

> Symbol table '.symtab' contains 18 entries:
>     Num:    Value  Size
>   Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
> ...
>     11: 00000000     0 FUNC
>   GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _start

Add this object to your ld command :
`ld -m elf_i386 test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o`

> ... undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'...

Look for this new reference in object files. It is not so obvious to know which library/object files are used because of -L, -l options and some .so include other libraries. For example, `cat /usr/lib/libc.so`. But, ld with --trace option helps. Try this command
`ld --trace ... (collect2 parameters)`
At the end, you should find
`ld -m elf_i386 -o test test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/crti.o`
or shorter (cf. cat /usr/lib/libc.so) 
`ld -m elf_i386 -o test test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/libc.so /usr/lib/crti.o`

 It compiles but it does not run (Try to run ./test). It needs the right -dynamic-linker option because it is a dynamically linked ELF executable. (cf collect2 parameters to find it) 
`ld -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o test test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/libc.so /usr/lib/crti.o`
 But, it does not run (Segmentation fault (core dumped)) because you need the epilogue of the _init and _fini functions (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html). Add the ctrn.o object. 
`ld -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o test test.o main.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/libc.so /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/lib/crtn.o`
`./test`

> Hello, world

Comment: Thanks so much Stef for this :) Your answer does answer the question so I'll accept it. So basically in summary `_start` and the global offset table are just symbols added by other shared objects, there's no special treatment - that makes sense. Your methodology of looking through the shared objects and examing the symbols was also really helpful to see. Best of luck in your journey, will be worth-it in the end.

Comment: @Sam. Thanks a lot. If you want to go further but I can not help you (I am discovering this part) try the option --verbose with ld to see the linker script. After you could create your own script and use it with the -T option.