# Passing objects to GCC linker using a text file

Tags: gcc, linker

I had list of objects in a text file. Now i want to link these objects using ld.exe command in gcc. Is there some option/logic that allows me to do so?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this what makefiles for? I would look into that direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run manually produce an elf executable using ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031307/how-to-run-manually-produce-an-elf-executable-using-ld)

Answer (score 1):

> Now i want to link these objects using ld.exe command in gcc.

1. You should ~never use `ld` directly.
2. `ld` is not part of GCC, but rather a separate program (part of binutils).
3. Yes: gcc accepts response files, and you can link your objects like so:

   gcc -o foo @your_list.txt ...list required libraries here...